# Custom built ffmpeg with aac encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to build custom ffmpeg with all audio decoding and the native aac encoding, so I have `--disable-everything` and then enabling the stuff I need. In my config I have the following:

```
--enable-muxer=mp4
--enable-encoder=aac
```

However when I try to write an .m4a file with:

```
./ffmpeg -i bis.wav -strict -2 bis.m4a
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'bis.m4a'
bis.m4a: Invalid argument
```

What am I missing in my build for aac encoding?

I also have .wav encoding enabled and this is working fine for making .wav files.

Complete configure:

```
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-programs \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-everything \
    --enable-filter=aresample \
    --enable-decoder=aac \
    --enable-decoder=aac_latm \
    --enable-decoder=aac_fixed \
    --enable-decoder=ac3 \
    --enable-decoder=ac3_fixed \
    --enable-decoder=als \
    --enable-decoder=alac \
    --enable-decoder=mp1 \
    --enable-decoder=mp1float \
    --enable-decoder=mp2 \
    --enable-decoder=mp2float \
    --enable-decoder=mp3 \
    --enable-decoder=mp3float \
    --enable-decoder=mp3adufloat \
    --enable-decoder=mp3adu \
    --enable-decoder=mp3on4 \
    --enable-decoder=mp3on4float \
    --enable-decoder=als \
    --enable-decoder=vorbis \
    --enable-decoder=flac \
    --enable-decoder=wavpack \
    --enable-decoder=wmalossless \
    --enable-decoder=wmapro \
    --enable-decoder=wmav1 \
    --enable-decoder=wmav2 \
    --enable-decoder=wmavoice \
    --enable-decoder=pcm* \
    --enable-bsf=mp3_header_decompress \
    --enable-bsf=aac_adtstoasc \
    --enable-bsf=chomp \
    --enable-bsf=remove_extradata \
    --disable-swscale \
    --enable-swresample \
    --enable-parser=aac \
    --enable-parser=aac_latm \
    --enable-parser=ac3 \
    --enable-parser=flac \
    --enable-parser=ac3 \
    --enable-parser=vorbis \
    --enable-parser=mpegaudio\
    --enable-demuxer=aac \
    --enable-demuxer=ac3 \
    --enable-demuxer=eac3 \
    --enable-demuxer=aiff \
    --enable-demuxer=flac \
    --enable-demuxer=latm \
    --enable-demuxer=mp3 \
    --enable-demuxer=ogg \
    --enable-demuxer=eac3 \
    --enable-demuxer=xwma \
    --enable-demuxer=pcm* \
    --enable-demuxer=wav \
    --enable-protocol=file \
    --enable-muxer=pcm* \
    --enable-muxer=wav \
    --enable-muxer=mp4 \
    --enable-encoder=pcm* \
    --enable-encoder=aac \
    --enable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-swscale-alpha \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="-fPIE -pie $ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
```

Comment: @LordNeckbeard no, I updated with my complete configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You need one more

The "iPod" muxer is probably needed for M4A.

```
--enable-muxer=ipod
```

---

### Other stuff

They can be combined into one line if you prefer:

```
--enable-decoder=aac,ac3,flac
```

Also, if you want to enable all options per component you could use:

```
--enable-decoders
```

This works for the other components as well (muxers, demuxers, decoders, encoders, filters, etc).

Comment: May also add that you can also use asterisk/wildcard to cover all suffixes: `--enable-decoder=aac*,ac3*,flak`